Sort entries by related categories when using Sprig filtering & pagination
tl;dr
Craft 4.8.6; Sprig 2.8.0
When using Sprig for filtering entries by related categories, and for pagination, how can I sort the listing of entries according to the order of some of those category groups?
I'd like to be able to do this, but it doesn't work:
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'properties',
    limit: 24,
    with: ['propertyDealTypes','propertyStatus'],
    orderBy: ['propertyDealTypes','propertyStatus'] <<<<< This line breaks things
}) %}

...

{% set pageInfo = sprig.paginate(entries, page) %}

I get the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'order clause'.

The full explanation
I have a section called "Properties". Property entries can be related to various categories (eg. "Deal Type", "Property Status", etc) through Category custom fields on the entry.
Separately, there's a "Page Builder" Neo field, with a block called "Properties", which displays a filterable list of those "Property" entries.  Content managers can select which filters will be made available to visitors, and whether the list of Properties should be forced/restricted to a specific category:

I'm using Sprig to handle the filtering and pagination. In the _neoBlocks/properties.twig file, I have this:
{% set forceRegion = block.forceFilters.region.one().slug ?? null %}
{% set forcePropertyType = block.forceFilters.propertyType.one().slug ?? null %}
{% set forceDealType = block.forceFilters.dealType.one().slug ?? null %}
{% set forceStatus = block.forceFilters.propertyStatus.one().slug ?? null %}

{# Filters #}
{{ sprig("_components/properties", {
    showRegions: block.availableFilters.contains('regions'),
    showPropertyTypes: block.availableFilters.contains('propertyTypes'),
    showDealTypes: block.availableFilters.contains('dealTypes'),
    showStatuses: block.availableFilters.contains('statuses'),
    region: forceRegion,
    propertyType: forcePropertyType,
    propertyDealType: forceDealType,
    propertyStatus: forceStatus,
})}}

And in _components/properties.twig, the relevant bits (only focusing on the "Deal Type" and "Status" categories) are this:
{# Init vars #}
{% set propertyDealTypeId, propertyStatusId = null, null %}
{% set urlQueryParams = {} %}

{% set propertyDealType = propertyDealType ?? '' %}
{% set propertyStatus = propertyStatus ?? '' %}

{% if propertyDealType is defined and propertyDealType|length %}
    {% set urlQueryParams = urlQueryParams|merge({
        propertyDealType: propertyDealType
    }) %}
    {% set propertyDealTypeId = craft.categories().slug(propertyDealType).ids() %}
{% endif %}

{% if propertyStatus is defined and propertyStatus|length %}
    {% set urlQueryParams = urlQueryParams|merge({
        propertyStatus: propertyStatus
    }) %}
    {% set propertyStatusId = craft.categories().slug(propertyStatus).ids() %}
{% endif %}


{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'properties',
    limit: 24,
    with: ['propertyDealTypes','propertyStatus'],
    propertyDealTypes: propertyDealTypeId,
    propertyStatus: propertyStatusId
}) %}

{% set page = page ?? 1 %}
{% set pageInfo = sprig.paginate(entries, page) %}
{% set pageEntries = pageInfo.pageResults %}

{% do sprig.pushUrl( '?' ~ urlQueryParams|merge({
    page: page
})|url_encode ) %}

{# ...and further down, after the code to show the filtering dropdown fields... #}

{% if pageEntries|length %}
    {% for entry in pageEntries %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {# etc... #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{{ include("_includes/pagination-sprig") }}

